# How to format the json date format using spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot and gradle for creating a rest service. Now I need to format the json date in the form of "yyyy-MM-dd", i.e, the format should be dateOfBirth: "16-03-2015", but I am getting "dateOfBirth: -751181400000". I added the below piece of code in my Apllication.java class, but still not able to get the desired output.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({ ObjectMapper.class, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.class })
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder()
{ 
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(); 
    builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
    return builder; 
}
```

And Application.java:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SubjectServiceConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@ComponentScan({"com.billing"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

Kindly help me out in resolving this issue.

Comment: For a give date, what output do you get and what was the desired output?

Comment: Hi Alvaro sorry for not providing the details. I require dateOfBirth: "16-03-2015" but I am getting dateOfBirth: -751181400000.

Comment: What is the method signature of the REST endpoint returning the date?

Comment: public ResponseEntity<Resource<BillDetails>> getBilling(@PathVariable String id)

Answer (score 21):

With Spring Boot, you should be able to set the default way that Jackson formats dates by setting the following property in your application.yml/application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.date-format= # Date format string (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), or a fully-qualified date format class name (e.g. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat)
```

Comment: Adam Thanks for your reply. It works fine for Spring-boot alone but not with Spring-boot and Spring-Hateoas. Kindly help me out. Or is there are any alternatives to acheive this.

Comment: Where you configure your objectMapper, make sure that this serialization feature is set: `objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);`

Comment: it's almost *too* obvious