# @NotNull for date validation in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bean-validation

I want to validate incoming date format (it should only accept date format) with specific format of `(DD/mm/YYYY)`

which annotation shall i use to see that date is not null

```
@NotNull
private Date myDate;
```

Comment: so look at the Bean Validation API, rather than tagging it as JPA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format the json date format using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077617/how-to-format-the-json-date-format-using-spring-boot)

Comment: I am trying to validate incoming request. I resolved this by creating validator class for validating date.